# Java: Apply Callback to Array Values

Tags: java

I'm looking for a simple way to apply a callback method to each element in a String array. For instance in PHP I can make all elements in an array like this:

```
$array = array_map('strtolower', $array);
```

Is there a simple way to accomplish this in Java?

Comment: What does that line do? It's not exactly expressive.

Comment: @skaffman - PHP's strtolower() function returns a string lower cased, similar to Java's .toLowerCase(). The function above applies (maps) the strtolower() function to each element in $array, thus returning an array with all elements lower cased.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no one-liner using built-in functionality, but you can certainly match functionality by iterating over your array:

```
 String[] arr = new String[...];

 ...

 for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
     arr[i] = arr[i].toLowerCase();
 }
```

Comment: +1 While there are are interesting answers to solving the question listed, sometimes, especially for someone learning a new language, straight forward and simple trumps clever.

Comment: I'm gonna have to go with this answer. The other answers are fine examples of mapping array items, but the solutions are much more complicated than simple iteration, which is what I was trying to simplify.

Answer (score 7):

First, object arrays in Java are vastly inferior to `List`s, so you should really use them instead if possible. You can create a view of a `String[]` as a `List<String>` using `Arrays.asList`.

Second, Java doesn't have lambda expressions or method references yet, so there's no pretty way to do this... and referencing a method by its name as a `String` is highly error prone and not a good idea.

That said, [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) provides some basic functional elements that will allow you to do what you want:

```
public static final Function<String, String> TO_LOWER = 
    new Function<String, String>() {
      public String apply(String input) {
        return input.toLowerCase();
      }
    };

// returns a view of the input list with each string in all lower case
public static List<String> toLower(List<String> strings) {
  // transform in Guava is the functional "map" operation
  return Lists.transform(strings, TO_LOWER);
}
```

Unlike creating a new array or `List` and copying the lowercase version of every `String` into it, this does not iterate the elements of the original `List` when created and requires very little memory.

With Java 8, lambda expressions and method references should finally be added to Java along with extension methods for higher-order functions like `map`, making this far easier (something like this):

```
List<String> lowerCaseStrings = strings.map(String#toLowerCase);
```

Comment: I want to accept your answer, because this is about how I expected it would be done. But man.. That is one hefty library to add to my project for only a single use. :/

Comment: @mellowsoon: Trust me, there are a lot of other reasons to use Guava. This is just one small example.

Answer (score 1):

You could use reflection:

```
String[] map(java.lang.reflect.Method method, String[] array) {
  String[] new_array = new String[array.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) new_array[i] = (String)method.invoke(null, new Object[]{array[i]});
  return new_array;
}
```

Then you just need to declare a static method somewhere and get a reference to it using the reflection API.

Comment: As annoying as it is to have to create verbose classes for this sort of thing, reflection is really not a viable choice. The necessity of using error-prone string literals for method names (which break if a method is renamed) and the lack of any kind of safety as far as the parameters and return type of the method go make this extremely fragile.

Comment: You're absolutely right about that, but it's definitely not something I'd like to see emulated anywhere.

Comment: What kind of overhead is there? Invoke vs. calling a method directly vs. ColinD's example.

Comment: I've never measured it but I suspect the reflection API has lots of overhead.